# how to access variables in google map api to use in every function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having problem utilizing the autocomplete of google map search. Here is what i am trying

```
function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    //add map, the type of map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: haight,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();      
    });

    alert(lat);
}
```

If i try to generate alert out of addlistner function it is not working, but it is working inside the addlistner. Is there any way i can access the lat,lng out of this addlistner?

And also can i use variable lat,lng outside of initialize function in runtime?

**EDIT**

```
var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  title: 'Point of origin'
});

// Add circle overlay and bind to marker
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 1000*10,    // metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});

circle.bindTo('center', markers, 'position');
```

I want to use lat,lng variable to create marker for generating circle to particular latitude and longitude.

Comment: Yes you can. Declare your variables out of the listener. But be careful... this is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Thanks for reply it is still saying undefined.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That might be useful information if you want help. Update your question with what you did (code) and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Sorry for any inconvenience, i've edited the question.

Comment: Well just create your marker/circle from within the listener...

Comment: i tried it, when i do this, it does'nt show anything can you show me what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    //add map, the type of map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: haight,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

        markerAndCircle(lat, lng);
    });
}

function markerAndCircle(lat, lng) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: 'Point of origin'
    });

    // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        radius: 1000 * 10, // metres
        fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
}
```

This is untested. If it doesn't work, watch your javascript console for errors and report here.

Note: the `map` variable is now declared outside of the `initialize` function as we need it in the `markerAndCircle` function.